# mean - MongoDB, Express.js, Angular2, node.js (backend setup and boundaries)

Tags: node.js, angular, express

I have the basic question how the frameworks and platforms **Angular 2** and **Express.js** in the 'mean' approach works together and where are the boundaries between client-side and server-side.

After reading much stuff to this topic I understand, that by calling the basic URL of the website (SPA) the Angular2-application will be send completely as package to the client (browser) where the (angular logic) will dynamically change the views by javascript in the client-browser as defined.

I also have create an angular2 SPA with some components, routing and services.

**Now I have the general question to the backend.**

I want to create a backend on the basis of node.js with the express.js framework.

*-How I have to setup the entire Angular2 (frontend) application in the express.js backend application because express.js based on MVC too?*

*-Where are the boundaries between the model and view of angular (MVVC)  and express.js (MVC) and where they play together?*

It would be great if somebody can name me references, tutorials or relevant stuff to this specific topic.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In reference to the MEAN stack, Express.js is not used as the MVC, but Angular is.  Express.js serves as middleware / a framework to help build your API quickly than if you just wrote in Node.js (Express.js is a framework for Node.js).

What you said here:

> calling the basic URL of the website (SPA) the Angular2-application will be send completely as package to the client (browser) where the (angular logic) will dynamically change the views by javascript in the client-browser as defined

Is exactly right, Angular 2 will act as the MVC, in browser, where the client will dynamically change views. Express.js will help you define the "basic URL" i.e. localhost:8000/ and what "package" as you have described, is sent to the client.  This "package" is your entire Angular application.

One of my favorite tutorials is from Scotch.io, though it is Angular 1.x, it's still helpful for building any MEAN stack application.

https://scotch.io/tutorials/creating-a-single-page-todo-app-with-node-and-angular

The line

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

Tells the application where to find all your JS / CSS / HTML files, or in your case, your Angular application. (Make sure your Angular application is in the directory that you list above relative to your Express/Node.js application)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much for your helpful answer! Now this approach is much clearer and I will study your named tutorial. That means I can install my entire angular2 application with node_modules and other dependencies of package.json in the defined folder of express.js (public) with reference to angulars index.html? all other node modules and dependencies for express.js I install on parent folders of server-side application (which acts primary as api for angular with db connection  and perhaps for other webservice calls) which will have a much lesser folder structure as when express.js act as MVC.

Comment: there are a couple of ways you can manage dependencies, one way I do it for my angular app is through CDNs and reference them my index.html, another way is using the Bower package manager.  You could use node_modules for both Angular and Express, but not all NPM packages can easily be referred to in your index.html.  NPM packages are more friendly for Node.js and Express.js.  You'll want to start thinking of Express.js less as the MVC, but more of helping bringing the (M)odel to your Angular application.